# Constant 0xc000012d Errors and program crashes

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hard-drive, partition

Our primary server had a low disk space problem which was preventing many of our remote users who connect to the server from being able to use many features of programs, as well as causing the server to work slowly.

I saw that the cause of this was a poorly partitioned primary disk, which only allocated 63GB to the C drive, which had approximately 1 MB of free space, meanwhile the adjacent F drive had 600 GB allocated with 200GB free. To resolve this what we did was back up the F drive, followed by converting the disk to dynamic, deleting the F partition, extending the C partition by 100GB, recreating a F partition with 500GB allocated, and finally transferring the backed up files to the F drive.

After doing this we have regularly been having programs crash and close. Most of the programs do not even provide an error message, but the few that do provide a generic unhandled exception error, or 0xc000012d error. Almost every program had regular crashes, from Adobe Reader to Internet Explorer.

What might be causing the crashes, and how can we attempt to fix this problem?

The server in question runs Windows Server 2008 R2, has a 1 TB primary disk, and 16 GB RAM.

After running CHKDSK on both drives here are the two logs that have been returned for the two respective drives.

Checking file system on C: The type of the file system is NTFS. A disk check has been scheduled. Windows will now check the disk. CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 5)... Cleaning up instance tags for file 0x3898. Cleaning up instance tags for file 0x75f9. Cleaning up instance tags for file 0xcfba. Cleaning up instance tags for file 0xf916. Cleaning up instance tags for file 0x19d84. Cleaning up instance tags for file 0x2d889. Cleaning up instance tags for file 0x2ef9a. Cleaning up instance tags for file 0x33c15. Cleaning up instance tags for file 0x43297. Cleaning up instance tags for file 0x4aa96. Cleaning up instance tags for file 0x4b65f. Cleaning up instance tags for file 0x4fb4d. Cleaning up instance tags for file 0x57f74. Cleaning up instance tags for file 0x5f1b5. 446464 file records processed. File verification completed. 6994 large file records processed. 0 bad file records processed. 0 EA records processed. 860 reparse records processed. CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 5)... 578550 index entries processed. Index verification completed. 0 unindexed files scanned. 0 unindexed files recovered. CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 5)... 446464 file SDs/SIDs processed. Cleaning up 4360 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9. Cleaning up 4360 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9. Cleaning up 4360 unused security descriptors. Security descriptor verification completed. 66044 data files processed. CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal... 33870528 USN bytes processed. Usn Journal verification completed. CHKDSK is verifying file data (stage 4 of 5)... 446448 files processed. File data verification completed. CHKDSK is verifying free space (stage 5 of 5)... 25703285 free clusters processed. Free space verification is complete. CHKDSK discovered free space marked as allocated in the master file table (MFT) bitmap. CHKDSK discovered free space marked as allocated in the volume bitmap. Windows has made corrections to the file system. 169406463 KB total disk space. 65791840 KB in 323636 files. 244704 KB in 66045 indexes. 0 KB in bad sectors. 556775 KB in use by the system. 65536 KB occupied by the log file. 102813144 KB available on disk. 4096 bytes in each allocation unit. 42351615 total allocation units on disk. 25703286 allocation units available on disk. Internal Info: 00 d0 06 00 3d f2 05 00 37 c8 0a 00 00 00 00 00 ....=...7....... 51 0f 00 00 5c 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 Q.............. 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................ Windows has finished checking your disk. Please wait while your computer restarts.

Checking file system on F: The type of the file system is NTFS. Volume label is PhData. A disk check has been scheduled. Windows will now check the disk. CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 5)... 712448 file records processed. File verification completed. 10 large file records processed. 0 bad file records processed. 0 EA records processed. 0 reparse records processed. CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 5)... 733330 index entries processed. Index verification completed. 0 unindexed files scanned. 0 unindexed files recovered. CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 5)... 712448 file SDs/SIDs processed. Cleaning up 46 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9. Cleaning up 46 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9. Cleaning up 46 unused security descriptors. Security descriptor verification completed. 10442 data files processed. CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal... 35028640 USN bytes processed. Usn Journal verification completed. CHKDSK is verifying file data (stage 4 of 5)... 712432 files processed. File data verification completed. CHKDSK is verifying free space (stage 5 of 5)... 73395282 free clusters processed. Free space verification is complete. Windows has checked the file system and found no problems. 491519999 KB total disk space. 196823200 KB in 701617 files. 287844 KB in 10443 indexes. 0 KB in bad sectors. 827823 KB in use by the system. 65536 KB occupied by the log file. 293581132 KB available on disk. 4096 bytes in each allocation unit. 122879999 total allocation units on disk. 73395283 allocation units available on disk. Internal Info: 00 df 0a 00 88 dd 0a 00 61 97 14 00 00 00 00 00 ........a....... fb 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ................

Comment: Are the crashing programs installed on C drive? Have you run a filesystem check on both partitions?

Comment: Some programs which crash are installed on the C drive while others which crash are on the F drive. I have not run filesystem check yet as it requires that the server be offline while running which would disrupt the work of other people using it. I will run it in around an hour and will post the results here.

Comment: I have added the Chkdsk logs for both the C and F drive.

Comment: I'll add an answer for that.

Comment: Is it possible that the crashes are the result of poor virtual ram allocation? I am not sure if the old F drive was set up to store the pagefile for the computer. I know that when I check the RAM usage when we experience the highest frequency of crashes, it is fluctuating at about 98-100%. Furthermore one of the crashes displayed a RAM related error message. Is it possible that the enabling of a system managed pagefile on the C drive will fix the problem?

Comment: It sounds as a bad memory problem. Try doing one or two passes with memtest86 and let us know if some errors are detected.

Comment: After several passes of memtest no errors were found. It seems as if the problems stopped occurring since the time when I set it to allow a system managed pagefile on the C drive. I think that what might have happened was that the system was configured to only have a pagefile on the F drive, and when the F drive was deleted, that setting was removed, creating too heavy of a load on just the physical memory.

Comment: I will add this as an answer as it seems as it has fixed the problem. Thank you for your assistance with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems ceased occurring after I configured the system to create a system managed pagefile on the C drive. It appears that the setting prior to the deletion of the F drive, had set only the F drive to have a pagefile. When the F drive was deleted, this configuration must have also been removed, which left only the physical memory to deal with the load remaining.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be related to filesystem inconsistencies.

`chkdsk` on both `C` and `F` drives should solve the problem.

Comment: I have already run chkdsk on both C and F drives. The logs have been added to the question. The problem still persists despite this though so I do not believe that it has solved the problem.